# Eloquent sobreescribe campos con nombres idénticos en Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Que tal ? Tengo dos tablas.. **empresas** y **communes**, cada empresa pertenece a una Comuna. Al ejecutar una consulta en el controller me di cuenta que communes sobrescribe los campos que tienen en común con empresas. **id, created_at, updated_at**. Me percaté que se sobrescribía ya que id:21 "que es el principal " debería corresponder a id de la tabla empresas , estaba tomando el id de la tabla communes. Alguna idea de ocurre y como solucionarlo? seria engorroso listar cada campo en el select cuando haya un join de 5 tablas.

En este ejemplo justo tengo la tabla communes en inglés, si la hubiese tenido en español tambien se sobrescribiria el campo nombre , campo que tienen varias tablas es por eso que preciso solucionarlo ahora .

caso 1 Solo tabla **Empresas** con sus valores originales:

```
        $misEmpresas=Empresa::join('communes','communes.id','=','empresas.commune_id')
                              ->where('empresas.user_id',auth()->user()->id)
                              ->latest('empresas.id')
                              ->select('empresas.*')
                              ->get();  
        return $misEmpresas;
```

Resultado caso 1 :

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "user_id": 31,
    "commune_id": 21,
    "nombre": "sushi-roll",
    "logo": "empresas/I3WqjmwUN2rIHsUhBT780QVjsTe6X7gnjo9OkdGn.webp",
    "direccion": "asdjk",
    "presentacion": "kjdas90",
    "created_at": "2021-03-21T17:39:34.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-21T17:39:34.000000Z"
  }
]
```

caso 2 Solo tabla **Communes** con sus valores originales:

```
        $misEmpresas=Empresa::join('communes','communes.id','=','empresas.commune_id')
                              ->where('empresas.user_id',auth()->user()->id)
                              ->latest('empresas.id')
                              ->select('communes.*')
                              ->get();  
        return $misEmpresas;
```

Resultado caso 2 :

```
[
  {
    "id": 21,
    "region_id": 4,
    "name": "Antofagasta",
    "created_at": "2021-03-19T19:30:17.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-19T19:30:17.000000Z"
  }
]
```

caso 3 , esta consulta es la que hice al principio, sin select . y se ve como se sobrescribe el di, created_at, updated_at .

```
        $misEmpresas=Empresa::join('communes','communes.id','=','empresas.commune_id')
                              ->where('empresas.user_id',auth()->user()->id)
                              ->latest('empresas.id')
                              ->get();  
        return $misEmpresas;
```

Resultado caso 3

```
[
  {
    "id": 21,
    "user_id": 31,
    "commune_id": 21,
    "nombre": "sushi-roll",
    "logo": "empresas/I3WqjmwUN2rIHsUhBT780QVjsTe6X7gnjo9OkdGn.webp",
    "direccion": "asdjk",
    "presentacion": "kjdas90",
    "created_at": "2021-03-19T19:30:17.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-19T19:30:17.000000Z",
    "region_id": 4,
    "name": "Antofagasta"
  }
]
```

Comment: Pero por que en el primer y segundo caso seleccionas valores de una tabla distinta?, lo digo por que se supone buscas un mismo resultado

Comment: no es que lo sobreescriba Sospecho que ambas tablas tienen campos comunes y al no entender cuál es cuál, o a qué tabla pertenece, siempre te arrojará los resultados de la primera tabla seleccionada. Creo que deberías hacer uso de los aliases.

Comment: @BetaM Lo hice para que vean los valores de los registros y que se entienda que en el caso 3  se sobrescribe.

Comment: @gaidyjg Claro tienen campos comunes, y la idea es saber si existe alguna manera sin tener que en el select estar nombrando columna por columna ya que a veces hay muchas tablas  relacionadas y seria mas engorroso.

Comment: Usar las [relaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) de Laravel / Eloquent

Comment: Deberías entonces indicar en el `select` no solo la columna sino además la tabla a la que pertenece para evitar esa confusión o cuidando los datos renombrarlas para evitar este comportamiento, de otra forma vas a seguir con ese problema

Comment: @gaidyjg Si exacto, tuve unas problemas con filtrar  consultas con 3 tablas relacionadas anteriormente y por eso intenté este método. pero  revisaré nuevamente a ver que tal. Lo bueno de esto es que con cada error se aprende.